# Why was Sara put in a box?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, pentateuch-chumash, genesis-bereishith, imahot-matriarch-mothers

Rashi in [Bereishis 12:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.12.14.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says;

> ויהי כבוא אברם מצרימה. הָיָה לוֹ לוֹמַר כְּבוֹאָם מִצְרַיְמָה? אֶלָּא לִמֵּד שֶׁהִטְמִין אוֹתָהּ בְּתֵבָה, וְעַל יְדֵי שֶׁתָּבְעוּ אֶת הַמֶּכֶס פָּתְחוּ וְרָאוּ אוֹתָהּ:
> ויהי כבא אברם מצרימה

> AND IT CAME TO PASS WHEN ABRAM WAS COME INTO EGYPT —It should have said, “when they were come into Egypt”; but the use of the singular teaches us that he hid her in a chest, and when they demanded the custom dues they opened it and discovered her (Genesis Rabbah 40:5).

In [Bereishis 12:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) however, Avraham told Sara to say she is his sister;

> אִמְרִי־נָ֖א אֲחֹ֣תִי אָ֑תְּ לְמַ֙עַן֙ יִֽיטַב־לִ֣י בַעֲבוּרֵ֔ךְ וְחָיְתָ֥ה נַפְשִׁ֖י בִּגְלָלֵֽךְ׃

> Please say that you are my sister, that it may go well with me because of you, and that I may remain alive thanks to you.”

If she was saying she was his sister, why would Avraham have to put her in a box as well? Assuming that this was a form of hishtadlus, why would he need 2 types of hishtadlus? Secondly, they traveled quite a bit, and so they probably knew there was a customs border and the box would be opened, what was the plan? Wouldn't it look suspicious to have a person in a box and then say she is your sister?

Comment: "Wouldn't it look suspicous to have a person in a box and then say she is your sister?" Wouldn't it always look suspicous to have a person in the box?

Comment: @doubleaa that is a fair point, I was just saying that if he was trying to throw them off that it is his wife, by hiding her he was giving them a reason to be suspicous that he was hiding something and not believe that she was a sister.

Comment: Maybe that was a normal way to transport sisters? Maybe you could always say she was being annoying? It's just so hard for us to get in the head of what a random prehistoric egyptian border control officer would suspect in any given situation.

Comment: IIRC, "she's my sister" insight came much later, when she was taken to Pharaoh as an Hishtadlus to prevent his sure death. His original idea was to prevent this in the first place by hiding her in the box.

Comment: As Rasi usually recycles Midrashim, it's worth to attribute the idea to its originator - Bereishis Rabbah: https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.40.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @double AA Years ago when I used to fight with my sister, I once used this as a proof that sisters belong in a box and are meant to be quiet. However, I now realize that this may not be the real true pshat........

Comment: @al berko In passuk 13 he already says she should say she is his sister, that wasbefore they actually arrived in Egypt

Comment: @Chatzkel It probably was seen as a reasonable pshat not too many years ago. That's why teaching historical sexist material needs to be done carefully. It's very easy for kids like you were to abuse it (not trying to pick on you, I'm sure you regret it and have grown up, I'm just using it as an example)

Answer (score 1):

I heard in the name of Rabbi Emanuel Gettinger zt"l the pshat that the "box" was on wheels. It was a carriage.

Hopefully they don't peek inside, and if they do, be prepared to say "she's my sister."

Comment: Doesn't sound like that from Rashi. Was this some modern day person you heard it from or you read it somewhere noteworthy

Comment: If someone's only ever been taught to read the word in Rashi one way, they can't see it any other way. The Gemara talks about someone traveling from Israel to outside Israel "in a box." Doesn't "coach" make more sense? Heard in the name of R' Emanuel Gettinger zt"l -- the man R' Hutner wanted to be the next Rosh Yeshiva of Chaim Berlin. Noteworthy enough for me.

Comment: In any event the intent of the Rashi and Midrash is clearly that Avraham actively tried hiding Sarah. It's not really hiding her if it's just a regular carriage, and "he hoped" she wouldn't be noticed.

Answer (score -3):

In keeping with the plain meaning of the text the way Rashi says his commentary does, and in keeping with the Bereshit Rabbah 12:13 quoted, doesn't it seem more likely that he is saying that Avram concealed his wife, Sarai in "a word"? (Like in ראשי תבות, ראשי תיבות)

That if her status as his wife was revealed, the Torah would have said, "they came to Egypt..."emphasizing that they *plural* are together as a married couple and came to Egypt.

But by his concealing that status through the term he used to describe her (my sister), the Torah only emphasizes Avram's coming to Egypt individually (*not as a married man*) even though she accompanied him. When the tax collectors investigated, they discovered her true status demanding more taxes (שתבעו את המכס).

In other words, this story is discussing the idea of how taxes are determined (***in both cases, truthfully***) according to how you declare objects, something common to anyone who travels abroad or, for example, makes aliyah, as in immigration to another country.

If you declare a possession in a particular taxable category, *for example a tapestry that can hang on the wall as artwork*, the taxes will be higher. If declared in another category, *in the example, it can also be declared as a rug to cover your floor*, the tax is lower. In both  cases, the declaration is truthful, but one will bring a much higher tax rate and the resulting financial loss.

In the case of immigration, taxes on property are often not applied for essential items that a single household brings with them. But duplicate items above those essentials are taxed. If Avram and Sarai immigrate as married, the duplicate items of Sarai's household would be charged tax to Avram. What's more, Avram was not entitled to use the items from Sarai's household to pay the tax charged to him because those items do not belong to him in the type of marriage they  had.

Tax collectors try to determine if belongings are declared properly in order to collect more tax. Anyone who has been involved with aliyah knows this situation well. If declared wrong, it can cost a great deal of money needlessly. Like is known, causing needless financial loss is considered in halacha to be a danger to life (סכנה נפשות). *See in this context Sefer S'dei Chemed, on the subject of selling a Beit Kenesset within a Jewish community where it results in a drop in the property value of those Jewish homeowners who remain behind.*

Just to clarify further, early Indian (Ceylon) and Arab (pre-Islamic) practice at that time had 2 forms of marriage, ***Digah marriage*** and ***Binah marriage***. In ***Binah marriage***, the wife retains her own property, household and inheritance rights.

This is the origin of the term and idea that women, meaning wives are given *"Binah Yiterah"* like is found in Shas and elsewhere (See [Niddah 45b](https://www.sefaria.org/Niddah.45b.11?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Sotah 35b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.35b.9?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Torah Temimah to Devarim 11:19:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Torah_Temimah_on_Torah%2C_Deuteronomy.11.19.6?vhe=Torah_Temimah,_Vilna,_1904&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

The wife in a Binah marriage is financially independent by law, more like a sister, than the wife of a Digah marriage, who is considered like property of her husband (her earnings and belongings become his).

It should be noted in this context, that the Matriarchs, Sarah, Rivkah, Leah and Rochel maintained their own households (their own tents) apart from the household of their husbands. In other words, the Avot were practicing ***Binah marriage*** as was the common practice where Avram and Sarai lived before coming to the land of Israel.

So in coming to Egypt, where the culture was different, Avram asked Sarai to declare herself as his sister, which was also true, in order that the entry taxes would be lower. They would be immigrating as two individuals with two separate households and the taxes charged to Avram would be substantially lower. Avram would not be *killed* (like mentioned above from the S'dei Chemed) with the additional taxes like is mentioned in [Bereshit 12:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.12?lang=bi&aliyot=0).

Additionally, both Avram and Sarai understood (*they were both wise*), before they ever reached Egypt, (see [Ba'al HaTurim to Bereshit 12:13 to אחותי את](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=173)) that it was likely that the Egyptians would try to acquire Sarai as a wife through the giving of gifts. She, at least, would be enriched materially. This is emphasized by both the commentary of [Ba'al HaTurim to Bereshit  12:12 on the word יחיו](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=173) and [Rashi to Bereshit 12:13 on למען ייטב לי בעבורך](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=173). It wasn't a surprise. They planned together how best to approach this situation and to profit from it materially. This is what is meant when Avram emphasizes that his life would be *bound/rolled up* with Sarai's future (והיתה נפשי בגללך).

So to summarize, the translation of the Hebrew doesn't mean that Sarai was hidden in a crate by Avram, like some abusive husband (Even the expression from Bereshit Rabbah, "נְתָנָהּ בְּתֵבָה וְנָעַל בְּפָנֶיהָ" is only referring to applying the term *my sister* to her and covering her face with a veil which was the common practice for all modest women when in public.), but rather that she (meaning her status as Avram's wife) was concealed by a single word, saying that she was Avram's sister.

Comment: Interesting thought!

Comment: @Chatzkel Based on the down vote, someone seems to prefer the idea of Sarah being locked in a box by an abusive husband! ;-)

Comment: "When the tax collectors investigated, they discovered her true status" the plain meaning of the text proves this is incorrect. They didn't discover her true status.

Comment: If Chazal and Rashi intended what you say they did, they wouldn't write נתנה בתיבה. Where do you see anything you wrote concealed in those words?

Comment: @robev You are assuming that 12:14-17 means that the tax collectors didn't know she was his wife. But Ishah means wife, not woman. The plain text would suggest that they considered Avram to be avoiding proper taxes. It is not clear why Avram was enriched financially from Pharaohs treasury (it seems like a dowery for a beautiful sister), but it is clear from 12:19-20 that the improper declaration was questioned directly by Pharoah. It may have been that the tax collectors decided that if you want to declare her as your sister, we will treat her that way.

Comment: @robev Either spelling of "teivah", with or without the Yud, can be read both ways (as word or chest). But if you consider what Avram actually did, he told Sarai to use one specific word in declaring her status to him. The plain sense of the text lends itself more to reading the Hebrew as "word" and not "chest".

Comment: What does פתחו וראו אותה mean according to this interpretation?

Comment: There's no way to read your peshat into the Midrash (he placed her in "a word"?), so are you suggesting Rashi isn't based on this Midrash (even though he clearly is), or he somehow saw this was Chazal's intent? In any event I have no reason to start making guesses as why the tax collectors didn't tell Pharaoh he had taken a married women, which was considered by all a crime, when I can read Rashi the way he intended I read him, kepeshuto, and have zero questions. Occam's Razor applies here.

Comment: @Alex It is like an idiomatic expression meaning opening a case to investigate it and see what is actually there. The tax collectors looked into the details of how the immigrants were declaring their property. Remember, double property would mean the duplication was wealth, not essential belongings of a single individual. Avram would have to pay a higher tax on the excess. And he couldn’t use Sarai’s estate to pay for it because it didn’t belong to him according to their Binah marriage. By saying she was his sister, each was entitled to their own tent, bed, etc. Lower tax, if any.

Comment: @robev How many Jewish wives can you think of who would entertain their husband’s request that they let him lock them in a trunk and smuggle them across the border into their new country so that it would be good for him? Remember, no duress and no one is chasing them. And Sarai is not just any regular wife. She is literally royalty and very wealthy. Does that seem plausible on any level?

Comment: @YaacovDeane That seems like a very forced read. And it's even worse if you look at the midrashim that Rashi is ostensibly taking this idea from.  Beresishis Rabbah says וְשָׂרָה הֵיכָן הָיְתָה נְתָנָהּ בְּתֵבָה וְנָעַל בְּפָנֶיהָ. That is quite explicit. Midrash Aggadah says הכניס שרה לתיבה כדי שלא יראו אותה המצרים. Also quite explicit.

Comment: Also, we have to consider these explanations in the context of the Biblical text. They are clearly trying to address an apparent discrepancy in the Biblical language -- if both Abraham and Sarah came to Egypt why does it say "he came" instead of "they came"? They accordingly explain that indeed only Abraham came, because Sarah was  hidden. According to your explanation, though, Sarah was in plain sight the whole time, so how have we answered the question of why does it not say "they came"?

Comment: @YaacovDeane extremely plausible. Much better than getting kidnapped by Pharaoh.

Comment: @Alex Midrash Aggadah, Midrash Rabbah, etc. is exactly that, midrash. All the language there is not to be presumed to be the plain meaning, like with Rashi’s commentary. Very often, when Rashi is looking to midrash, he is looking at how the language usage appears. He uses those grammar examples as indicators of how to properly understand the plain meaning of the text of the Torah. This type of approach follows the method advocated by Philon of Alexandria.

Comment: @Alex Sarai was only hidden as Avram’s wife via the single word he asked her to say, namely that she was his sister. That is the plain text of the Torah. Again, not false but not offering the additional information that she was his wife. How the tax collectors and Pharoah would respond to that was, like with all things, in the hands of Heaven. The practical hope of Avram was that he would not suffer economic loss via the taxes due for maintaining a Binah marriage. Ultimately, his words were fulfilled. He was enriched economically & they both departed Egypt unharmed and intact.

Comment: ונעל בפניה can't mean to "cover her with a veil". In any event doesn't it bother you that every Jewish scholar from Rashi until today understood Rashi's intent was that Avraham was an abusive husband, as you write? Clearly you're providing some clever reconstruction of Rashi's comment, but to dismiss the consensus on how to read it is a bit of hubris. Isn't the simpler explanation for how everyone missed the boat is that they are in fact correct in their understanding, that Avraham hid his wife in a box to save her life from danger?

Comment: Are you calling Yaakov abusive for hiding his daughter from Eisav by putting her in a box?

Comment: @robev https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78193/7303

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130457/discussion-between-robev-and-yaacov-deane).

Comment: @robev FYI, נעל as used in midrash can mean any type of covering, like in צעיף, which is used by women to cover their face even today.